# How to get Data Dynamically in Android Activity

Tags: android

I wanted to know that, I have Android Application having aroung 7 to 10 Activity which contains some form Control and Images, I want that Images should come from server if i have net Access and initially If I don't have the net Access then Default images should display, So can you tell me what is the best approach to do this as we can see the same things in Quikr or Snapdeal or Amazone App

Answer (score 1):

Use image loading libraries (Picasso, UniversalImageLoader or Glide)